# How to get the Installation path of binary and logic file in Daemon in Arch Linux

Tags: linux, command-line, arch-linux

I want to know that if i install a daemon service in Arch Linux, then what will be the path of the files that will get install. also which files will be install where.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you read `pacman(8)`?

To list all the files being installed by a particular package, run:

```
$ pacman -Ql <package_name>
```

Daemons are usually systemd services in Arch Linux, hence you could run:

```
$ pacman -Ql <package_name> | grep service
```

to see a list of service files installed by that package.

Comment: thanks for your reply :-) As  i am new in linux can tell me any service that i can check the files of ? I want to know if i am creating a service and have binary and other Abclogic.so file then where this file will go if i package this with AUR and install it on client machine

Comment: 1. If you are new to Linux, Arch is probably not the right distro for you.  
2. Services are essentially files.  
3. Read the ArchWiki on systemd and Creating Packages: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Creating_Packages

Comment: okay thanks for your suggestion. That was really helpful for me. Thanks :-)

Comment: can you tell me my my internet is not working in Arch Linux. I am connected with Broadband network. which command can start up that ?

Comment: Again ArchWiki is your best friend. Else start a separate question